# CSS Border radius and filter grayscale not working together

Tags: css, grayscale, css-filters, border-radius

I have some css in place that uses both a border-radius and a grayscale filter. I want the border radius to be in place all the time but the grayscale to disappear on hover.

The border radius works fine until I add in the grayscale, then it stops working and just shows the images as a square. On hover (when the filter is removed) the border-radius kicks in again. Does anyone know what I am missing?

I have searched but can't find an answer.

```
.esg-entry-media {
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50% !important;
    border-radius: 50% !important;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    filter: grayscale(100%);
}

.esg-entry-media:hover {
    border: solid 10px #fff !important;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
    filter: grayscale(0%);
}
```

I have included an image of the hover and non-hover states for reference.

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add a [mre].

Comment: how can the hover and the non-hover have a different image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a div to wrap around the image put an `overflow: hidden;` on it and give the div the same width and height. Then put border-radius: 50%; on the div. Only apply the grayscale on the image. At the end to change the img do,

```
div:hover .esg-entry-media{
  filter: grayscale(0)
}
```

On the wrapping div do,

```
div:hover {
  border: 10px solid *coloryouwant*
}
```

Comment: Thank you - this fixed it!!

Comment: Not a problem at all! Goodluck with your project.

Answer (score -1):

which browser? works fine for me (chrome, firefox, safari):

```css
.esg-entry-media {
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    border: 10px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 50%;
    filter: grayscale(100%);
}

.esg-entry-media:hover {
    border-color: #a00;
    filter: grayscale(0%);
}
```

```html
<img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300" class="esg-entry-media" />
```